# How can I effectively performance-profile Dynamics?

Tags: dynamic, performance-tuning, gui-construction

How to optimize performance-wise a complex dynamic expression (like a GUI) with lots of dynamically updated components, which require different update-frequencies?

I was hesitant to ask this question as it does not focus on a very specific problem, but is about general speed (and memory) improvement tricks. The gui is a primitive scrolling racer where the user has to manipulate a controller to keep an object on a winding path. I did it for a cognitive experiment for humans but it definitely has potential in the gaming market :) Also - as far as I know - *Mathematica* was not used (and was not designed) to develop realtime platformer/racer games (or alike), so the question naturally arises: can *Mathematica* do it? This, I think, is untrodden land worthy of exploration. Below is a toy model of a game. I tried to keep it as abstract as possible to make it general and thus applicable to a wider domain. If you still think that this question is too localized/not really a question, please say so and I remove it.

**Details of the code**

The code might seem too long, but I assure you, it is not complicated. If the game is started with the Start button, the function `start` initiates a `ScheduledTask` that sets the in-game timer with `updateFrequency = .05` seconds. The controller can be dragged continuously, and it generates a coordinate pair ${x_1, x_2}$, stored in `ctrl`, that is fed to the `controlFunction`, that defines the actual vertical position (`y`) of the yellow arrow (the "ship"). The responsible equation is:

$$
y = y* + k_1 x_1 + k_2 x_2
$$

where $y*$ is the $y$ value of the position of the arrow in the previous timestep. Now the hard part is, that from time to time, parameters $k_1$ and $k_2$ are randomly changed (every 100 steps, using the `change` function), so the controller is changed as well. The controller background always displayes the actual gradient of ${\varDelta}y$. The different background colors in each episode indicate that the controller has changed. I did not use `Locator` or `LocatorPane`, as those seemed to be unresponsive, especially when the underlying controller is changed. While the controller is updated continuously, the actual position of the arrow is only updated via the `update` function when the running `ScheduledTask` tells so (in every 0.05 sec). Also, moving the controller produces some sounds that helps the user to learn the control gradient.

```
DynamicModule[{
  optimumFunction = Sin[#*\[Pi]/100] &, (* defines the winding optimum zone *)
  updateFrequency = .05, (* update plot every 0.05 seconds *)
  xFrame = 100, (* horizontal range to show (last 100 steps) *)
  yFrame = 30, (* default vertical range to show *)
  maxTime = 1000, (* length of a run. Real word time is ~ 0.05 * 1000 = 50 sec *)
  episodeNum = 5, (* number of different episodes: each episode lasts 200 timesteps *)

  active, controlActive, ctrl, data, time, \[Theta], \[Rho], y, 
  yRange, xRange, gradient, crosshair, ship, episodeColors, 
  episodeBorders,
  reset, sound, start, stop, update, change, controlFunction
  },

 (* Internal functions *)
 reset[] := (active = False; ctrl = {0, 0}; data = {}; time = 0; y = 0; change[]; update@0);
 sound[{x_, y_}, vol_] := Sound[SoundNote[Floor@Rescale[controlFunction[x, y], {-1, 1}, {-20, 40}], .3, "Strings"], SoundVolume -> vol];
 start[] := (active = True; RunScheduledTask[update@(time++), {updateFrequency, \[Infinity]}]);
 stop[] := (RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]]; active = False);
 update[t_] := Block[{xAll, yAll, n = 2},
   y = y + controlFunction @@ ctrl; (* update the position of the ship *)
   data = Append[data, {t, y}]; (* save position of the ship *)
   yRange = ({Min[Min@#, -{-1.5, 1.5}], Max[Max@#, {-1.5, 1.5}]}*1.3) &@(Last /@ Take[data, -Min[yFrame, Length@data]]); (* calculate vertical and horizontal ranges to show on the scrolling plot*)
   xRange = {Max[0, time - xFrame], Max[xFrame, time]};
   xAll = N@Abs@(Subtract @@ xRange); (* absolute x-range shown *)
   yAll = N@Abs@(Subtract @@ yRange); (* absolute y-range shown *)
   \[Theta] = Mod[ArcTan @@ #, 2 \[Pi], 0] &@ If[t < n, {1, 0}, (data[[-1]] - data[[-n]])/{xAll, yAll}]; (* rotation angle of the arrow, dependent on previous steps and the actual plot range used *)
   If[0 < t < maxTime \[And] Mod[t, maxTime/episodeNum] == 0, change[]]; (* change controllers *)
   If[t >= maxTime, stop[]]; (* stop run *)
   ];
 change[] := (
   \[Rho] = RandomReal[{-.5, .5}, 2]; (* \[Rho] = {k1, k2}, the two random parameters of the gradient *)
   controlFunction = {#1, #2}.\[Rho] &; (* the control function defining the gradient *)
   gradient = 
    DensityPlot[(controlFunction[x, y]), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
     Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0,
     ImageSize -> 200, 
     ColorFunction -> ((Lighter@
          ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]]) &), 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Mesh -> {{{0, Thick}}},
      MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}];
   );


 (* Initialization *)
 crosshair = 
  Graphics[{White, Disk[{0, 0}, 1.5], Darker@Blue, Disk[], Blue, 
    AbsoluteThickness@1, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.5], Line@{{0, -2}, {0, 2}}, 
    Line@{{-2, 0}, {2, 0}}}, ImageSize -> 15];
 ship = Graphics[{FaceForm@Yellow, EdgeForm@{Gray, Thick}, Polygon@{{0, -1}, {4, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}}}, ImageSize -> 30];
 episodeBorders = Partition[Range[0, maxTime, maxTime/episodeNum], 2, 1];
 episodeColors = {Hue[.66, 1, 1], Hue[.13, .8, 1], Hue[.23, 1, .8], Hue[.5, .4, .6], Hue[.74, 1, .8]};
 reset[]; (* initialize first episode *)


 (* Output *)
 Panel@Grid[{{
     Column@{

       (* Buttons *)
       Row@{
         Dynamic@Button[If[active, "Stop", "Start"], If[active, stop[], start[]]],
         Button["Reset", stop[]; reset[]]
         },

       (* Controls *)
       Framed@Dynamic[
         If[! active, 
          Graphics[{}, Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 200, 
           ImagePadding -> 5, Background -> GrayLevel@.9],
          EventHandler[Dynamic[
            If[controlActive, ctrl = Clip@MousePosition@"Graphics"; EmitSound@sound[ctrl, .5]];
            Graphics[{
              Texture@gradient, 
              Polygon[{{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}}, 
               VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}],
              Dynamic@Inset[crosshair, ctrl]
              }, Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 200, ImagePadding -> 0],
            TrackedSymbols :> {controlActive}],
           {
            "MouseDown" :> (controlActive = True;), 
            "MouseUp" :> (controlActive = False;)
           }]],
         TrackedSymbols :> {active, gradient}]
       },

     (* Scrolling pane *)
     Panel[Dynamic[
       Show[
        (* background colors *)
        Graphics[MapThread[
          {FaceForm@{Opacity@.2, #1}, EdgeForm@None, 
            Rectangle @@ {{First@#2, -100}, {Last@#2, 100}}} &,
          {episodeColors, episodeBorders}], 
         PlotRange -> {Automatic, yRange}],

        (* initial/terminal gray edge (before time 0 and after maxTime *)
        Plot[0, {t, 0 - maxTime*.1, 0}, PlotStyle -> None, FillingStyle -> GrayLevel@.9, Filling -> {1 -> Top, 1 -> Bottom}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, yRange}],
        Plot[0, {t, maxTime, maxTime*1.1}, PlotStyle -> None, FillingStyle -> GrayLevel@.9, Filling -> {1 -> Top, 1 -> Bottom}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, yRange}],

        (* desired zone (winding path) *)
        Plot[{optimumFunction@t - .5, optimumFunction@t, 
          optimumFunction@t + .5}, {t, Max[0, time - xFrame] - 20, 
          Max[xFrame, time] + 100}, 
         PlotStyle -> {None, 
           Directive[GrayLevel[0, .7], AbsoluteThickness@3, Dashed], 
           None}, FillingStyle -> Hue[.3, 8, .8, .5], 
         Filling -> {1 -> {3}}],

        (* ship & trajectory *)
        Graphics[{GrayLevel@.6, AbsoluteThickness@2, 
          Dynamic@Line@Most@data, 
          Inset[Rotate[ship, \[Theta]], Last@data]}],

        (* options *)
        PlotRange -> {xRange, yRange}, 
        PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled@.02, Scaled@.2}, 0},
        ImageSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> Full, 
        ImagePadding -> Automatic,
        Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> False, Axes -> False, 
        GridLines -> {Range[0, maxTime, maxTime/episodeNum], None}, 
        Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}
        ], 
       TrackedSymbols :> {yRange, xRange, time, y, \[Theta], active}
       ], ImageSize -> {800, 400}]
     }}, Alignment -> {Left, Center}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I know that the best advice here is that

- only update if necessary;
- only update the smallest minimum that needs to be updated.

I was keeping that in mind during development. Most of the scrolling graphics are pre-generated (the sine wave and background colors as rectangles) and only the `PlotRange` is changed dynamically. Explicit `TrackedSymbols` are used to update only those symbols that should be updated. Still, the gui is lagging: the controller follows the moused with a reasonably large lag, that does not feel smooth. Also, during every episode change, there is a short pause. Now, this lagging is inacceptable: my first Commodore had only 64 KB memory, but it could run such games way smoother than *Mathematica*.

1. **How can I understand what uses up time during dynamic evaluation (considering that I do not want to print `AbsoluteTiming` values all the time)? How can I profile such a gui?**
2. **How can I improve the code further to give a smooth feeling?**

Any comments/ideas are welcome.

---

I should tell here that this code uses a lot of stuff from all around Mathematica.SE, so if you run into some familiar lines, don't be surprised. Thanks for all your helpful input. Also thanks for Oleksandr for the title!

---

**EDIT at 7. 8. 2012**

According to Rojo's profiling and comments [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5268598#5268598), here is a modified version of the scrolling output (just replace the original internal `Panel[Dynamic[Show[...]]]` with the code below. It removes the wrapping `Dynamic` around `Show` and instead uses a dynamically updated `PlotRange` (also I moved the `Dynamic`s in the ship and trajectory to the inside of `Inset` and `Line`). Now while this updates much faster, and any check on `xRange` and `yRange` indicates that they are updated correctly at every timestep, the displayed plot range is only updated when the controller is moved, meaning that if the controller is not touched, the ship will just move out of the range on the right (clearly unwanted).

```
Panel[Show[
  Graphics[MapThread[
    {FaceForm@{Opacity@.2, #1}, EdgeForm@None, Rectangle @@ {{First@#2, -100}, {Last@#2, 100}}} &,
    {episodeColors, episodeBorders}]],

  (* initial/terminal gray edge *)
  Plot[0, {t, 0 - maxTime*.1, 0}, PlotStyle -> None, FillingStyle -> GrayLevel@.9, Filling -> {1 -> 100, 1 -> -100}],
  Plot[0, {t, maxTime, maxTime*1.1}, PlotStyle -> None, FillingStyle -> GrayLevel@.9, Filling -> {1 -> 100, 1 -> -100}],

  (* desired zone ("road") *)
  Plot[{optimumFunction@t - .5, optimumFunction@t, optimumFunction@t + .5}, {t, 0, maxTime}, PlotStyle -> {None, Directive[GrayLevel[0, .7], AbsoluteThickness@3, Dashed], None}, FillingStyle -> Hue[.3, 8, .8, .5], Filling -> {1 -> {3}}],

  (* ship & trajectory *)
  Graphics[{GrayLevel@.6, AbsoluteThickness@2, Line@Dynamic@Most@data,Inset[Rotate[ship, Dynamic@\[Theta]], Dynamic@Last@data]}],

  (* options *)
  PlotRange -> Dynamic[{xRange, yRange}, TrackedSymbols :> {xRange, yRange}], 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled@.02, Scaled@.2}, 0},
  ImageSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> Full, ImagePadding -> Automatic,
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> False, Axes -> False, 
  GridLines -> {Range[0, maxTime, maxTime/episodeNum], None}, 
  Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}
  ], ImageSize -> {800, 400}]
```

Comment: It would be nice to investigate why it doesn't update properly, but it seems buggy to me... Just change that `Dynamic[{xRange` so something with sideeffects and it works. For example, `Dynamic[xRange=xRange;{xRange, yRange}]`

Comment: Better fix: Dynamic[Refresh[{xRange, yRange}]]`. Btw, fixed a few bugs in the profiler

Comment: @Rojo Indeed it works with `Refresh`, but it would be nice to know why it **does not work without it**. These are the inconsistent annoyances that make it so hard to master `Dynamic`. A more detailed explanation could be posted as an answer.

Comment: No idea why. Hope someone does, but I suspect, it's one of those bugs that make it hard to work with dynamic as you said ;). However, it's by using this more and reporting that we get them to improve this, right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'll post a function based on the title of the question. You wrap your dynamic code in `profileDynamics` optionally passing the option `"Print"->True` (defaults to `False`).
It should be noted that this can only profile the explicit `Dynamics` that are on the code. Nested dynamics that are generated at runtime are not profiled by this

```
ClearAll[profileDynamics];
Options[profileDynamics] = {"Print" -> False};
profileDynamics[d_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{print = OptionValue["Print"]}, 
  Module[{counter = {}}, 
   DynamicModule[{diag, start, tag}, 
    diag[] := 
     CreateDocument[
      Column[{Button["Reset counter", counter = start], 
        Dynamic@Grid[
          Join[{{"Dynamic expression", "Count", "Time"}}, 
           MapAt[Short, #, 1] & /@ counter]]}]];
    CellPrint@
     ExpressionCell[Button["See profiling information", diag[]]];
    d //. {i : Annotation[_, {tag, ___}] :> i,
       e : Dynamic[sth : Except[First[{_, tag}]], rest___] :> 
        With[{pos = 1 + Length@counter, 
          catalog = 
           Annotation[
            InputForm@e, {tag, Unique["profileDynamics`annot"]}]}, 
         AppendTo[counter, {catalog, 0, 0.}];
         Dynamic[
           First@{Refresh[
              If[print, Print[catalog]]; ++counter[[pos, 2]];
              (counter[[pos, 3]] += First@#; Last@#) &[
               AbsoluteTiming[Refresh[sth]]], None], tag}, rest] /; 
          True]} // (start = counter; #) &]]]
```

Applying this to the code in question yields

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A zoom to the most interesting part, tells us that the big `Dynamic[Show` was run 67 times for a total of half a second when I played a few seconds with the game.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can you also post an simple case and a screenshot of useful info in that case provided by `profileDynamics` ?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov, edited

Comment: Fixed a few bugs

Comment: Works beaurifully for the posted example. Though unfortunately it returns a table of 0 "Count" and "Times" values for the full version of my code (A much more complicated `DynamicModule`). I'm gonna do a bit of debugging...

Comment: Concerning nested `Dynamic`s: `ReplaceRepeated` obviously won't work because of infinite replacement. I've tried to apply a `replaceBackward` function instead of your `/.` which makes the replacements from inside-out. It recognized all the `Dynamic`s, but of course any outer `Dynamic` will be represented in the profiler report as an expression containing the code `profileDynamics` injected into it. One thing I can think of is to replace whatever was injected with the original when it comes to printing the results (i.e. structural replacements done inside the `MapAt`.

Comment: On v10, this (excellent) code shows [this syntax highlighting error](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55121/syntax-highlighter-shows-error-for-manipulate-when-its-inside-a-block-or-a-modu) for `counter` in the outermost Module, which will leak its value.

Comment: (More generally, is there a reason for `counter` to be in a `Module` of its own outside of the main `DynamicModule`?)

Comment: @episanty I don't have the code fresh in my head, but, probably, I thought the following at the time. It's not important to lose state between kernel sessions. DynamicModule wouldn't be any use (on the contrary) if we are using a multi-cell and multi-notebook apprach, and the new cell isn't spawned from a button inside the containing DynamicModule such that `InheritScope` works. As it is right now, if changing Module to DynamicModule works (haven't tried it) I think its because of a leak and it shouldn't